# About Regex word boundaries

Tags: regex, boundary

I have this string:

```js
s='''
D. JUAN:
¡Cálmate, pues, vida mía!
Reposa aquí; y un momento
olvida de tu convento
la triste cárcel sombría.
¡Ah! ¿No es cierto,
ángel de amor,
que en esta apartada orilla
más pura la luna brilla
y se respira mejor?
'''
```

If I want all the words strarting with a vowel:

```js
import re
print(re.findall(r'\b[aeiouAEIOU]\w*\b', s))
```

and the output is:

```js
['aquí', 'un', 'olvida', 'Ah', 'es', 'amor', 'en', 'esta', 'apartada', 'orilla']
```

Now, I try to list all words that do not start with a vowel:

```dart
print(re.findall(r'\b[^aeiouAEIOU]\w*\b', s))
```

and my output is:

```js
['D', 'JUAN', 'Cálmate', 'pues', 'vida', ' mía', 'Reposa', ' aquí', 'y', ' un', ' momento', '\nolvida', ' de', ' tu', ' convento', '\nla', ' triste', ' cárcel', ' sombría', 'No', ' es', ' cierto', 'ángel', ' de', ' amor', 'que', ' en', ' esta', ' apartada', ' orilla', '\nmás', ' pura', ' la', ' luna', ' brilla', '\ny', ' se', ' respira', ' mejor']
```

Comment: You need a lookahead, `r'\b(?![aeiouAEIOU])\w+'`

Comment: the "not" condition not only finds consonants, but also all kinds of other characters like spaces etc. and the `\b` could also match the word boundary from the previous word.

Comment: On a sidenote: do not forget accented letters like `á`

Comment: **Quick fix**, just add `\W` inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The `[^aeiouAEIOU]` negated character class matches *any* character other than `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `A`, `E`, `I`, `O` and `U`, so a linefeed char, or a `§` will also be matched if they are preceded with a word character (a letter, digit or underscore in most cases) as the negated character class is preceded with a `\b` construct.

So, you need to use

```py
re.findall(r'\b(?![aeiouAEIOU])\w+', s)
```

where `(?![aeiouAEIOU])` negative lookahead will make sure the `\w+` only matches one or more word chars where the first char is not equal to the letter inside the character class.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f5fxzt/1) (note that you must select the right engine in the regex101 options).

Note you do not need any `\b` at the end after `\w+`, since the word boundary is implied at that position.

Comment: Wiktor I really appreciate your help.  I am trying to understand what I did wrong, then I will skip to solve it. My steps were: 1) find a word boundary with \b 2) next the non-vowels with [^aeiouAEIOU] 3) find all \w and finally 4) another word boundary with \b.  Of course  I did something wrong, but can not see it yet...

Comment: @FranciscoHernández *The [^aeiouAEIOU] negated character class matches any character other than a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O and U, so a linefeed char, or a § will also be matched if they are preceded with a word character (a letter, digit or underscore in most cases) as the negated character class is preceded with a \b construct.* What is not clear?

Comment: @FranciscoHernández Did you get the gist about the "any character"? `[^aeiouAEIOU]` matches `§`, `—`, etc. Not just "letter that is not a vowel". Did it finally work for you?